# When clicking on a hyperlink jquery should work and the page should not navigate - jquery

Tags: jquery

I am displaying a text for example let us consider the text as "SOF".

When i clicking on the "SOF" text i show that specific site in my site with in a iframe.

This case is working fine...

**But my problem is when i click on the "SOF" text iframe is loading as well as the page is also totally navigating to the same page. This should not happen. I given my code here. What is the way to prevent from redirecting the whole site.**

**EDIT :**

**This URL is working fine : http://www.oercommons.org/browse/collection/free-ed-gov**

**This URL is not working : http://www.merlot.org/merlot/viewMaterial.htm?id=79516**

**What may be the issue.. :-(**

Note : I know there is no need for jquery to displaying the site in an iframe. But in my case some times i will display html, pdf etc... So I am in need to use jquery. :-)

```
var xhr = null;
    //by default set the element properties
    var preview_on = true;

    Drupal.behaviors.previewOverview = function(context) {
      //show preview on mouse over
      $('.links a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 4) {
          //if previous ajax is working then cancel it
          xhr.abort();
          //$('#right-sidebar-right').html('Preview Panel.');
        }
            if (preview_on) {
                curLink = this;
                targetLink = this.href;        
                data = '<div><a href='+ targetLink +' target="_blank">View Original Page</a></div>' + '<iframe src="' + targetLink + '" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>';
                // To display the data in selected area.
                $('#right-sidebar-right').html(data);
            }
        } else {
          $('#right-sidebar-right').html('Turn on preview mode to view.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just now i found the fact... merlot.org site has been preventing them from showing their site in iframe. So, the site loads in iframe and then instantly redirects to the URL via session.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could also do..

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" >google</a>


$('a').click(function(e){
    alert("do something");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Try tweaking an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UnnUZ/)..